# Google ReCaptcha not showing error when It is not filled umbraco custom forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, umbraco, umbraco7

I am new to dot net.I tried to display the errormessage when recaptha is not filled but ModelState.AddModelError not showing the error. so I have tried in this way but still the error won't  show in my view

**Model** my Modelfile

```
public class ContactFormViewModel{

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Required")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessageCaptcha { get; set; }     
    public string FeedbackField { get; set; }
    public string SubmittedFromUrl { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**  my controller file

```
public ActionResult SubmitFormAsync(ContactFormViewModel submittedForm)
    {


        RecaptchaVerificationHelper recaptchaHelper = this.GetRecaptchaVerificationHelper();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(recaptchaHelper.Response))
        {
            // ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please complete the reCAPTCHA");
            //  ModelState.AddModelError("reCAPTCHA", "The reCAPTCHA is incorrect");

            submittedForm.ErrorMessageCaptcha = "Email not found or matched";
            //  return CurrentUmbracoPage();
            return PartialView(submittedForm);
            // return View();
        }
        else
        {
            RecaptchaVerificationResult recaptchaResult = recaptchaHelper.VerifyRecaptchaResponse();
            if (recaptchaResult != RecaptchaVerificationResult.Success)
            {

                //  ModelState.AddModelError("reCAPTCHA", "Please complete the reCAPTCHA");
                //ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The reCAPTCHA is incorrect");
                submittedForm.ErrorMessageCaptcha = "Email not found or matched1";
                //  return CurrentUmbracoPage();
                return PartialView(submittedForm);
                // return View();
            }
        } 

        //FeedbackField is Honeypot captcha
        if (!ModelState.IsValid || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(submittedForm.FeedbackField))
        {}
```

**View** my view file

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="PageId" value="@currentPage.Id" />
            @Html.Recaptcha(theme: Recaptcha.Web.RecaptchaTheme.Clean)

            <p class="error-message">@Model.ErrorMessageCaptcha</p>
            @*@if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                @Html.ValidationSummary()

            }*@


            @Html.Label("error message", new { style = "display:none", id = "recaptchaErrorMessage" })

            <button type="submit" id="btn-form-submit" class="btn-secondary pull-right">@currentPage.GetPropertyValue("buttonText")</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. The validation is working fine. Replace these lines

> **Controller**

```
RecaptchaVerificationHelper recaptchaHelper = this.GetRecaptchaVerificationHelper();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(recaptchaHelper.Response))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("reCAPTCHA", "Please complete the reCAPTCHA");
                return CurrentUmbracoPage();
            }
            else
            {
                RecaptchaVerificationResult recaptchaResult = recaptchaHelper.VerifyRecaptchaResponse();
                if (recaptchaResult != RecaptchaVerificationResult.Success)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("reCAPTCHA", "The reCAPTCHA is incorrect");
                    return CurrentUmbracoPage();
                }
            }
```

> **View**

```
       <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                @Html.Recaptcha(theme: Recaptcha.Web.RecaptchaTheme.Clean)

                @{
                    var errors = ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
                }
                @if (errors != null && errors.Any())
                {
                    @Html.Label(errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage, new { id = "recaptchaErrorMessage" })
                }
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what version or recaptcha you are using but i have used it on a number of my custom forms i have build and if i am right be default the recaptcha button adds a extra input which when the form is submitted this gets added to your form data. So what i do on my forms is just check that extra field and create my own simple error message and return the current page with the error, like below:

```
var formData = Request.Form;
        var captchaRequest = formData["g-recaptcha-response"];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(captchaRequest) || !ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TempData["contactError"] = "Ops... Form Error, There was an error with your details please check them and try again.";
            return CurrentUmbracoPage();
        }
```

Remember the ModelState will be valid even without the recaptcha filled in, in my case its just a capture all message.

Comment: [link](https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-add-recaptcha-to-an-mvc-form/) i followed his tutorial add the recaptcha,The validation is working fine but the AddModelError or submittedForm.ErrorMessageCaptcha not showing error in View. in ValidationSummary() also it is not showing recaptcha error but it shows other error link required name etc

Comment: think your best bet is to then check (debug) your view when you get back to the page after submitting the form, either 2 things you error is not saved to the model or when the model gets back to the page it doesn't have the error on it, also not sure how you are submitting the form as i cant see  form around your view if its via javascript that might also be where the issue is.